# How to get the audit log of an entity in CRM 2016 using a web API

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, dynamics-crm-webapi

I have made a lot of research to get the log of changes for a specific entity using  Microsoft dynamics CRM 2016 web API in  , but that's useless I cannot find a way to did that.

I just found the `RetrieveAuditPartitionLis` which return collection of partitions, Response :

```
 "AuditPartitionDetailCollection": [
    {
      "PartitionNumber": 1,
      "StartDate": "2014-07-01T00:00:00Z",
      "EndDate": "2014-09-30T19:59:59.997-04:00",
      "Size": 9
    },
    {
      "PartitionNumber": 2,
      "StartDate": "2014-10-01T00:00:00Z",
      "EndDate": "2014-12-31T18:59:59.997-05:00",
      "Size": 8
    },
```

.....

I need a way to get the log of a specific entity for example /accounts/audit endpoint. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `audits` entity.

**End point** : `organization_domain/api/data/v8.0/audits`